# Plot from shapefile

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile

I have a .rar file that contains the following files:
.cpg
.dbf
.prj
.sbn
.sbx
.shp
.shp.xlm
.shx

I would like to plot an map, but I have no ideia how to do it.

I've searched online and I've tried to use geopandas

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sf= gpd.read_file('vao_lt_exemplo.dbf')
sf.plot()
plt.show()
```

and as result I got this image.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HUX1.png)

Comment: Probable the plot is correct, and the shapefile (all files with the extensions you listed together is called the shapefile format) just contains one record with a line. You can check the data present by using `print(sf)`